# Scala sort output on Key and then alphabetically

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark

I'm trying out my first Scala program to sort the following output such that when the value is identical, words are sorted alphabetically.

```
cookie   8
document   6
function   5
name   5
start   5
```

My current code is as follows:

```
object Problem1{
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val inputFile = args(0)
    val outputFolder = args(1)
    val kValue = args(2)
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Problem1").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val input = sc.textFile(inputFile)
    val words = input.flatMap(line => line.toLowerCase().split( [\\s*&#^'''\\,..:;?!\\[\\](){}<>~\\-_]+"))
    .filter(x => x.matches("[A-Za-z]+")&& x.length >2)
    .map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).map(_.swap)
    val freq = words.sortByKey(false,1).map(_.swap).take(kValue.toInt)
    val topKrdd = sc.parallelize(freq)
    val tabSeperated = topKrdd.map(f => f._1 +"\t" + f._2)
    tabSeperated.saveAsTextFile(outputFolder)
  }   
}
```

Can someone help me with the alphabetical sort for the lines where the numerical value is identical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually Scala provides and uses an implicit `Ordering` for methods like `sortByKey`, but you can also construct a custom one and pass it in explicitly. The `Ordering` trait and companion object have a fair few helpful methods for this. You could do this:

```
val ord = Ordering.Tuple2(Ordering[Int].reverse, Ordering[String])
val freq = words.takeOrdered(kValue.toInt)(ord).map(_.swap)
```